# how to pass variable instead of number in sendcommand in autocad python

Tags: python, autocad

how to pass variable instead of number in sendcommand

```
acad.doc.SendCommand('QLEADER ' '0,500' '\n' '200,1000 ''\n' '500 ' 'ABC \n' '\n' )
```

this works but

```
a=0
b=500 
acad.doc.SendCommand('QLEADER ' 'a,b ' '\n' '200,1000 ''\n' '500 ' 'ABC \n' '\n' )
```

but this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try using f-String:

```
a=0
b=500 
acad.doc.SendCommand('QLEADER ' f'{a},{b} ' '\n' '200,1000 ''\n' '500 ' 'ABC \n' '\n' )
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).